# Find application size on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

Google Play site on PC doesn't show application size. Additionally, after last update, Play Store application doesn't show application size either.

Is there a way to find application size without downloading/installing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the app and in the website, you can only get the size of the APK.

[image]

But for additional downloads (extensions), it's usually not documented, but they can go to as much as 4GB. See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330911/max-size-of-an-android-application

In some cases, it just says "Varies with device".

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, or if they remove it, you can alway tap on install. When you see the size, cancel it. :D

Comment: google playstore not giving me size info* when i tap install